# PYTHON | MYSQL - Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to get the data I got as a result of scraping into my mySQL database.  The only problem is I can't figure out this error.

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''news_tb' ('title', 'summary', 'date') VALUES (' Price Analysis 5/22: BTC, ETH, ' at line 1
```

Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mysql.connector
import datetime

# connecto to the database
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='root',
    password='password',
    host='localhost',
    database='news_db'
)

cursor = cnx.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO 'news_tb' ('title', 'summary', 'date') VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

def crawl_url(article_arr):
    url = "https://cointelegraph.com/tags/bitcoin"
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    ## Scrape articles
    articles = soup.findAll("article", {"class":"post-card-inline"})
    try:
        for article in articles:
            title = article.find("span", {"class":"post-card-inline__title"}).get_text()
            summary = article.find("p", {"class":"post-card-inline__text"}).get_text()
            date = datetime.datetime.today()
            article_arr.append((title, summary, date))
    finally:
       return article_arr

article_arr = crawl_url([])
#print(len(article_arr))
cursor.executemany(sql, article_arr)
cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Can someone help me with my code? Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have exported earlier to a `.csv` file, and the data that I am **scraping** should be fine.

Comment: Use backticks not single quotes, or remove entirely: `INSERT INTO news_tb (title, summary, date)`

Comment: @danronmoon It worked! Thanks!
Somehow I cant check off your comment as right answer for this post.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment